# Is it possible to pass variables to styled-components without using props?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am wondering if it is possible to pass variables to a styled-component from without passing them through props.

for example:

Tried the code below

```
let isActive = false;

const myClass = () => <div className="myDiv">Hello</div>

export default styled(myClass)`
  .myDiv {
    ${isActive ? 'color: green' : 'color: red'}
  }
`;
```

I should expect that the div font color would be red.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If you are going to reuse the component, having a local or global variable is not going to help you out.

Comment: Maybe you'll find [this link](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props) helpful

Comment: @Gasim let's assume I have a function that sets the isActive flag to true when I click on the div. and let's assume that I'm reusing this component three times.

I only want the one that was clicked to rerender, not all three.

if all three render with the isActive prop set to true, then all three will be green

Comment: This is the exact point of props. Here is the docs regarding passing props: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props

Comment: This is a question on how to implement what you just described in your comment. Treat `isActive` as a conditional to decide on what styles should be applied to the divs in question